# SQL check id value from multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to count the number of ids based on a certain condition.

I have a table with 3 columns: id (not unique), foo (integer), and bar (string).

```
    id| foo | bar   
     1|  0  | yes    
     1|  1  | no
     1|  1  | no    
     2|  0  | no  
     2|  1  | no    
     3|  0  | yes
     3|  1  | no
     3|  2  | yes
     4|  0  | yes
```

I want the query to give me a list of ids. The condition:

```
a. id should have more than 1 entry.  
b. id needs to have foo = 0 AND bar = yes.  
c. if (b) is satisfied, it also needs to have all the rest of foo to have bar = no. (the number of foo for each id is unknown)
```

In the above example, the query should return id = 1.    (Id = 2 is
invalid because bar = no when foo = 0.   Id = 3 is invalid because bar
= yes when foo = 2.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of `id`s using `group by` and `having`.  An exact translation of your conditions is:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having count(*) > 1 and
       sum( foo = 0 and bar = 'yes' ) = 1 and
       sum( bar = 'no' ) = count(*) - 1;
```

You can use a subquery if you want the count instead of the list.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I never thought that 'having' can have multiple clauses. Cheers.